# In SQL or GQL or JDOQL, how can I query for the row that has the highest value in 2 columns (that have the lowest difference)?

Tags: sql, algorithm, google-app-engine, jdoql

Say for example I have a table:

```
Table: Message
| data | likes | dislikes |
```

How can I **efficiently** find the row that has the highest number of likes and dislikes i.e. most controversial. So for the following example:

```
{("Hello", 10, 5)
("Ola!", 5, 5)
("Ni Hao!", 2, 2)
("Wazzup!", 5, 7)}
```

"Hello" would be chosen.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to rethink your criterion for "most controversial": do you really want to rate ("foo",1,1) more controversial than ("bar",100,99)?

Comment: Hey thanks for noting that. I wasn't thinking properly. I edited the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You might want to use some other metrics instead of `abs(likes - dislikes)`. In this case, `(0, 5)` and `(100, 105)` will be equally controversial.
I think, `likes*dislikes` might work in your conditions.

2) I'm not sure about `jdoql`, but since you specified sql tag, in standard sql this can be done without sorting. Something like

```
select * from Message 
    where likes*dislikes = (select max(likes*dislikes) from Message)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Yup thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I restated the question to better suit the word "controversial" lol.

Comment: @AppEngineNoob You can execute this query in any relational database, just put your own metrics in (it appears you want `likes + dislikes`).

Answer (score 2):

GQL (assuming you're using the app engine datastore) won't be able to do a query on a calculation.

You would need to add another property to your model (eg called 'controversy'), and calculate it every time you change the number of likes or dislikes. Then you could do a simple query on that other property (ie in descending order, then fetch the first N records).

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 (likes+dislikes ) as sumOfLikesDislikes from Message 
order by sumOfLikesDislikes desc
```

As suggested by Nikita, you can use (likes*dislikes) as LikesTimesDislikes (for metrics) if you want.

You can even do both :

```
select top 1 (likes+dislikes ) as sumOfLikesDislikes, 
             (likes*dislikes ) as LikesTimesDislikes  
from Message 
order by sumOfLikesDislikes desc, LikesTimesDislikes   desc
```

(First by sum, then by metrics)